# Python libraries for mulit-armed bandit problems

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, multi-armed-bandits, contextual-bandits

I am working on a problem that can be casted as a contextual bandit problem with continuous action space. I would like to tackle it by using something like the *contextual zooming* algorithm from the paper [Contextual Bandits with Similarity Information](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/slivkins14a/slivkins14a.pdf).

Is there any open source implementation (possibly in python) of this or other contextual bandit algorithm?

I am not an expert of MAB so I might be wrong, but it seems to me that the field lacks the equivalent of SB3 or rllib for Reinforcement Learning. I find it quite puzzling given that MAB problems are a very well studied special case of RL and they are mathematically better understood.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks a lot!